# Delete duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

I have written a query to find the duplicate rows in a table. It outputs duplicate pairs (e.g.    `row: 1,2`  after that you enounter `row: 2,1`)

```
SELECT m1.ID, m2.ID
FROM AccessLog_Manual m1
    INNER JOIN AccessLog_Manual m2 ON 
        m1.ACCESS = m2.ACCESS AND 
        m1.EMPLOYEEID = m2.EMPLOYEEID AND
        m1.LOGDATETIME = m2.LOGDATETIME AND
        m1.MORPHOACCESSID = m2.MORPHOACCESSID AND
        m1.ID <> m2.ID
ORDER BY m1.ID
```

Now I want to use this query in a delete statement, such that removing *only* one row of pairs. (i.e. for example `row 1,2` and `row 2,1`, only delete `1` and let `2` non-deleted)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some allow you to delete with a JOIN, some don't.

Comment: @MattGibson Sql Server

Comment: @jso This question is different. My query outputs duplicate pairs, appear ascending then descending.

Comment: Oh, have a look into this one then (it's not directly for SQLServer but it gets to the point): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921501/find-duplicates-or-more-in-mysql-delete-them-except-the-first-one-input?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` to assign numbers to rows you consider duplicate.  A number above 1 means the row is duplicate.

For example:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by ACCESS, EMPOYEEID, LOGDATETIME, MORPHOACCESSID
                    order by ID) as rn
        ,       *
        from    AccessLog_Manual
        )
delete  numbered
where   rn > 1;
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/449dc/2/1)

Comment: How can I delete duplicate rows (as question states)?

Comment: No need for the `in`. Can just delete from the CTE directly http://stackoverflow.com/a/3822833/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith: Interesting, updated in answer.  @Kilanny: the query in the answer deletes duplicates (using the `delete` statement)

Comment: @Kilanny: The condition on `rn > 1` ensures that the first row survives. The `order by ID` clause means the remaining row will have the lowest ID of the group.

Comment: Why did you abuse your dupe hammer to reopen this obvious duplicate? Your answer is now the same as the one I linked to?